# Creating a new instance of a class outside constructor with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, linq, dependency-injection, unity-container, data-transfer-objects

I am trying a sample application to test out dependency injection. Before using DI, I have the following method in my class:

```
public IQueryable<BookDTO> GetBooks()
{
    var books = from b in db.Books
                select new BookDTO()
                {
                    Id = b.Id,
                    Title = b.Title,
                    AuthorName = b.Author.Name
                };

    return books;
}
```

BookDTO is a data transfer object defined in another project. Now I want to loosely couple my projects together. So I created IDTOBase interface and made BookDTO implement this. I have a unity container where I have made the relevant registering of the BookDTO class to IDTOBase.

But how will I rewrite the LINQ query in my original method? What will take the place of "new BookDTO()"?

Thanks

Comment: The purpose of DI is not to loosely couple data, but to loosely couple logic layers.

Answer (score 7):

You start off with part of the answer I think: 'BookDTO is a data transfer object'. As such there is little value in abstracting it as it belongs in a very specific layer of your application.

The BookDTO has the role of being a purely data representation of a book (in some presumably serializable form). This will occur at a low level in your application stack. Any code that requires the use of such data should create a domain object 'Book' that can be used in the code. This decouples the persistence and retrieval of the book data (BookDTO) from it's domain representation (Book).

Your interface definition I don't think serves this purpose and so DI doesn't serve a purpose here. Where I feel DI comes into play here is in the retrieval of Book DTOs. A class that loads book data would have such a service injected and use it to retrieve BookDTO instances.

Comment: I am a bit confused with your last paragraph. My EntityFramwork stores Book entity. But the business logic uses BookDTO. So I have ServiceLayer which has the GetBooks() function that retrieves Book object and maps it into BookDTO. In this case, where should DI be implemented? If I understand your answer, then the ServiceLayer should not use any DI, but my business layer can use DI to abstract the ServiceLayer class. Should my business logic reference BookDTO directly?

Comment: Yes your business layer would use DI to abstract the service layer. This way you can test the business layer components in a controlled manner against known mock/stub behaviours. Your business layer should map BookDTO to a business layer representation 'Book' so the two can change independently otherwise you are coupling layers together. Have a look at AutoMapper for support for mapping objects between layers: http://automapper.org/

Answer (score 0):

Well, whoever instantiates the object will need to know what actual type to make it.

What it looks like you need is some sort of repository, which knows about `IDTOBase`, as well as `BookDTO`.  Your application would know about `IDTOBase`.  You're application would make a call like `BookRepo.GetBooks`, in which your repository signature would look like `IQueryable<IDTOBase> GetBooks`.

Answer (score 0):

You need another class that can resolve the dependency for you.

In most cases of DI you say **"Give me a 'class' and resolve any mapped Interfaces it has to its mapped class instance"**, what you need is that 'class.'

I liked some of these examples when I was learning DI. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection